# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'login' (but the database exists)

Tags: php, mysqli

I get this error when I submit the login form.

The database named login does exist.

[image: you can see it here]

[image: The error picture]

I'm using wamp

This is the PHP code:

```
$servername ="localhost";
$dBUsername="root";
$dBPassword="";
$dBName="login";

$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$dBUsername,$dBPassword,$dBName);

if (!$conn) {
die("Ni uspilo:".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: i experienced strange errors like this too in wampp or some other "cool" webservers. i suggest you to download and use apachefriends.org ,xampp and you will be surprised.I use xampp since 2002 and i have no surprises like this one.

Comment: @Constantin WAMP works just as well as any other web server.

Comment: yeah i know that: with several errors.. free

Comment: XAMPP  is free too, so I am not getting your point @Constantin

Comment: OP change `$servername ="localhost";` to `$servername ="localhost:3308";` as WAMP installs MySQL and MariaBB databases and typically runs the MySQL database on port 3308.

Comment: you should try use in develop xampp to understand the point